# DotNet dev-cert with Chrome

Tags: docker, google-chrome, .net-core, ssl-certificate

Scenario:

1. DotNet Core 3.1 web application template in Visual Studio

[image]

2. Configure for HTTPS running in Linux Docker container

[image]

3. Click to run on Docker

[image]

4. Click 'Yes' to accept dev cert

[image]

5. Get Not Secure error in Chrome

[image]

Please someone explain how to fix this. I have run `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` then `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` more times than I care to count. I have exported the cert from Personal -> Certificates and imported into Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates. Chrome still only sees the one in Personal, even after full reboot of machine. If I remove the Personal one, VS just makes me accept again and Chrome still only sees the one in Personal.

It should not be this difficult to create a project from a template and just hit run.

Before some mod marks this as a DUPLICATE, I have spent HOURS going through similar questions on here as well as ways of verifying the cert is making it to the Docker image. Nothing has worked.

HOW is this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

I did the following:

1. Close all browsers (Chrome+Edge)
2. Make sure all background tasks for Chrome is closed (Ctrl+Shift+Esg) and close all of them.
3. Run the following commands:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This worked for me, cheers!